# Play sound from one side (lateralized) in PsychoPy

Tags: python-3.x, audio, psychopy

I'm trying to play sound from either the left or the right side / speaker / headphone side. So far, I haven't found a solution to this problem. I can play sound but I can't adjust it, so that the tone is lateralized.

```
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

logging.console.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)  # get messages about the sound lib as it loads

from psychopy import sound, core

print('Using %s (with %s) for sounds' % (sound.audioLib, sound.audioDriver))

alert = sound.Sound(700, secs=0.12, sampleRate=44100, stereo=True, hamming=True, volume=0.8)

alert.play()
core.wait(0.4)

core.quit()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the PsychoPy Sound documentation https://www.psychopy.org/api/sound.html, sounds can be specified in several ways, including:

> • Or a string could represent a filename in the current location, or mediaLocation, or a full path combo
>
> • Or by giving an N × 2 numpy array of floats (-1:1) you can specify the sound yourself as a waveform

In either case, the sound file or the array needs to contain different information in the left or right channel. At the moment, you are specifying a constant tone of 700 Hz which will be played identically through both the left and right channels.